# ¿Cómo llamo una variable interna de una función, fuera de ella?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
def onClicked(self, button):
self.lista.append(button.text()[0:])
t_matrix = np.transpose(matriz)
#selected_matrix = self.lista
self.listados = []

for elemento in range(len(self.lista)):
    self.listados.append(t_matrix[letters[self.lista[elemento]]])
print(self.listados)
selected_matrix = self.listados
t_selected_matrix = np.transpose(selected_matrix)

common_features = [ [features[i],list[0]] for i, list in enumerate(t_selected_matrix)
                    if all(x == list[0] for x in list) ]

for feature in common_features:
    #print (feature[0], feature[1])
    print ("[", values[feature[1]], " ", feature[0], "]")
```

Lo que deseo es poder llamar a la variable common_features fuera de la función, porque resulta que en la salida me repite la operación tantas veces como apriete los botones. Es decir, me gustaría que esta sección de código descrita pueda estar fuera de la función, aun cuando common_features dependa de la variable tambien interna t_selected_martrix

```
common_features = [ [features[i],list[0]] for i, list in enumerate(t_selected_matrix)
                        if all(x == list[0] for x in list) ]

    for feature in common_features:
        #print (feature[0], feature[1])
        print ("[", values[feature[1]], " ", feature[0], "]")
```

[image: Esta es la Matriz, donde las cabeceras de fila(rasgos) y de columna(sonidos) son importantes]

[image: Estos son los botones que eligen a los sonidos para compararlos según los rasgos]

La Intención es que al escoger los botones los vaya agrupando en la variable selected_matrix, que luego es traspuesta para dar como resultado la variable t_selected_matrix, la cual servirá para comparar los rasgos comunes entre los sonidos seleccionados, ese resultado será almacenado en commom_features. La cuestión es que me repite esa operación y por ello quiero implementar un botón ok para indicar queya ha terminado la selección.

Comment: Ya que usas POO simplemente haz que la variable sea un atributo de instancia, con lo que será accesible desde cualquier método de tu objeto.

Comment: Te refieres a usar otra clase?

Comment: Por ejemplo, quiero que al terminar elegir con los botones, con otro botón OK, me pueda hacer esa segunda parte del código, al menos llamar a ese ciclo for.

Comment: En ese caso puedes hacer otro método de insatancia que envuelva el código que muestras al final y que se llamado al pulsar el botón Ok y hacer que t_selected_matrix sea un atributo de instancia. Sería más fácil construir una respuesta si agregaras un [mcve] para poder ver la lógica de tu app.

Comment: Hola JSevilla, habrá otra forma en que nos podamos comunicar? tiene que ver con las preguntas que he hecho anteriormente. Voy a editar yy agregar unas imagenes para que pueda ponerte en contexto.

Comment: @FJSevilla por falee el comentario antes de este.

Comment: He mirado tus  publicaciones anteriores, ¿es Pyqt5 verdad?. La idea sería crear un nuevo botón asociado a un método que se encargue de todo lo que haces aquí menos de agregar el carácter a self.lista. Tienes varias cosas que creo que se podrían simplificar pero sería de gran ayuda que pudieras proporcionar el código completo o al menos una parte mínima funcional. Ahora mismo hay variables que no se sabe de que tipo son ni su contenido como `matriz`, `features` o `letters`.

Comment: En cuanto a la comunicación no tengo problema en crear una [sala de chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=es.stackoverflow.com) para poder hablar de forma más fluida sobre el tema si te interesa.

Comment: Si me interesa lo de la sala de chat.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70892/discussion-between-fjsevilla-and-jean-gotopo)